# Is it possible to know if SELECT TOP clause has reached top amount of results?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

### Context:

I'm using MS Access 2010 to run some simple queries from a vb.net windows app.
I have a table named "machines" and I want to get up to 100 machines with some filtering criteria, so I'm using this query: `SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Machines WHERE Speed <= 1500;`

### Question

When I get 100 rows as result, is there a way to find out if there are more rows in the table or if there were just 100? What I want to do is just show users a message to let them know if there is more data than it is shown or not.

---

### Note:

I could just do this: `SELECT TOP 101 * FROM Machines WHERE Speed <= 1500;`
list only 100 results if limit is reached and show users a message, however I was looking for a more elegant solution.

Many thanks in advance, this is my first question so some constructive criticism about how to post a question would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the `TOP 101` method is not an inelegant solution.

One alternative would be to use two queries.  First run:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) RowCount
FROM Machines 
WHERE Speed <= 1500;
```

And then run your actual data query.  This will return the number of rows regardless of how many you intend to use.  The drawback is that it takes two queries.

Alternately (and I'm not sure Access supports this syntax) you can do a subquery at the same time as the regular query like so:

```
SELECT TOP 100 *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Machines WHERE Speed <=1500) AS RowCount
FROM Machines 
WHERE Speed <= 1500;
```

However, this has the disadvantage of returning the row count with each row, which increases the amount of data in transit.  It's also a [trivial] cross join, which may take additional processing time.  Furthermore, it still is running two queries like the above; it's just simultaneous.  Whether those are likely to be significant problems for a simple query is up to you.

Comment: I'm starting to think that TOP 101 wasn't that bad. Both of your options would work so I'm choosing this as the correct answer.
Second option seems less efficient, so I would rather choose the first one. However, as I have to list machines anyway I think doing only one query (TOP 101) is neater.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the total count and check if it is greater than 100 (if you decided to show only the TOP 100), then you can tell the user that there are more records not shown

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 100 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS MoreRecords
   FROM Machines
  WHERE Speed <= 1500;
```

Comment: I have tried your query (and some variations of it) and it seems not to work on MS Access 2010. Thanks anyway.